# Ember.js 0.9.7.1 -> 0.9.8.0, breaking changes?

Tags: ember.js

I've been following through the tutorial / guide published here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-emberjs.html

Which has been a great help at getting me started with Ember.js, however, I have found that whilst the code in his examples work with Ember.js version 0.9.6, they do not work with the 1.0 pre version. My handlebars code that should generate a list item for each item in the `App.labelController` just does nothing when using the newer version. Is this an intentional change? If so, how do I go about achieving the same effect now?

**EDIT:** I've actually narrowed down the breaking change to between version **0.9.7.1** and **0.9.8**

I have the following code (for reference):

```
  /**************************
  * Application
  **************************/

  // Create the Ember.js application framework
  App = Em.Application.create();

  /**************************
  * Models
  **************************/

  // The "model" for the label object
  App.Label = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    svg: null
  });

  /**************************
  * Views
  **************************/

  /**************************
  * Controllers
  **************************/

  // The "controller" for the label objects
  App.labelController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function() {
      // Fake some data arriving from the server
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        var label = App.Label.create({
          id: i,
          name: 'Label 0' + i,
          svg: null
        });
        this.pushObject(label);
      }
    }
  });
```

And the following HTML:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">        
    <div class="span3">
      <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
          {{#each App.labelController}}
            <li>
              <a href="#">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </script>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span9" id="drawContainer">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `this._super()` on the `App.labelController#init` method.

Here is your JSFiddle: [it does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/3cJGD/).

And the JSFiddle with the call to `_super`:  [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/ekNap/).

Comment: Sorry, but but that's the first I've ever heard of the `this._super()` call; what does it do? Why is it needed? etc.

Comment: When you specify the `init` method on an object, it overrides the `init` method of the extended class. So calling `this._super()` ensures the parent method is called (and prevent unexpected behavior). Here, it calls this method: http://goo.gl/pXsFw

Comment: Ah ofc, as I'm overriding the base classes function.. Makes sense! Do you need to do this for everything you override in Ember then?